# What is use if this code $resultPage->setActiveMenu() in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

```
$resultPage->setActiveMenu('Panacea_Images::author')
```

I have created a custom module for images and this is my menu name **Panacea_Images::author**, but it's not working.
Can anyone explain the logic behind it and how the function work and the parameter which i pass, where the call will go from that line ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When adding the new items to Admin menu, we should declare the menu items in our module. For example:

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Vendor_Module::index" title="Vendor Index" module="Vendor_Module" sortOrder="61"
             resource="Vendor_Module::index"/>
        <add id="Vendor_Module::index" title="Vendor Index" module="Vendor_Module" sortOrder="10" parent="Vendor_Module::author"
             action="vendor_module/module/index" resource="Vendor_Module::index"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

The config above will create the new menu item  with its sub.
In your controller, we can set the activated menu item with `setActiveMenu` method (id of menu item is the param).

Comment: setActiveMenu() is only used to activate the menu which we have define in menu.xml file?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: when we call the setActiveMenu() function is there any file is executed ?

Comment: Have to call in the controller. You should take a look this file: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Backend/App/AbstractAction.php#L133

Comment: sir can you go through the custom module which i created?

Comment: @MandarParbate your module is already on Github or somewhere else?